# Is it possible to determine the type to be constructed when using @JsonCreator for deserializing in Jackson?

Tags: java, json, jackson, deserialization

I was hoping that when using inheritance I could reduce boilerplate code by implementing default  constructor/builder method in interface, like:

```
public interface IFace {
    @JsonCreator
    default <T extends IFace> T buildIFace(@ActualJsonTypeToBeConstructed Class<T> clazz,
            @JsonProperty String someString) {
        // calling some factory that constructs the actual type by string in a very generic manner
        return null;
    }
}
```

The annotation `@ActualJsonTypeToBeConstructed` is just an example how it might be possible. Currently this is possible only if I copy the same code to each class and get the actual type to be constructed there but this is just what I want to avoid.

So is there any way to catch the actual type that Jackson tries to deserialize?

Or is the some other way? Like in Gson I might be able to implement TypeAdapterFactory or so.

Comment: Well this is hard found a one search solution without coding it... neither you can use a protocol to determined type or not use JacksonMapper, you are think in library manipulated json raw in runtime memory like "org.json" ??

Comment: Try access to data with org.json and use a Builder patron for default data, you get something like jackson if value isn't present maybe be null or default value